# What's a word for "a person who strives to be unique"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

English buddies! I've got *presque vu* today.

I'm looking for an adjective or noun that connotes:

1. A risk-taking individual
2. A unique individual
3. An individual who isn't content with following in the footsteps of others.

I feel like a word for this *does* exist, but I can't think of it! (In other words, college application essays frustrate me.)

I'd be grateful for any help!

EDIT: Thank you all so much! I need it because my counselor wanted me to describe myself in 3 words...which is difficult. I appreciate all the words :)

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the word would be used?

Comment: Sounds like a **maverick** (helpfully, the word can be a noun or an adjective).

Comment: Depending on context, **iconoclast** may also fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **iconoclast** means someone who breaks (with) outmoded traditions.  It doesn't specifically denote a risk-taker, but it does have those connotations.  By its origins, it denotes a social reformer, but it's most often used now just to indicate someone who refuses to (as you indicated) follow in the footsteps of others.

> **Iconoclast**: a person who criticizes or opposes beliefs and practices that are widely accepted.
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iconoclast

The word comes from those who literally broke "icons" or religious images, out of the belief that they were superstitious and/or idolatrous.

Answer (score 6):

A frequently used noun would be "Trailblazer" - owing to the concept of the first person to enter an unknown, potentially risky area.  The term is used in nearly any application where innovation, and a fearless disregard for conventional wisdom are involved , i.e. Medicine, Technology, Sports, etc.

Example:  "Dr. DeBakey was considered by most to be a true *trailblazer*, a pioneer in Cardiac surgeries"

Comment: The ***avant-garde*** (from French, "advance guard") has a meaning very similar to that of "trailblazer".

Comment: This might be a bit of an over-reach for a 16 year-old kid.